# Is it a good idea to embed Drool rule engine in STORM topology?

Tags: drools, apache-storm

I am using STORM for real time processing. I want to embed the drool rule engine in one of the bolt.
Is this good design or idea? Because STORM is meant for fast real time processing and gives good performance at the rate of 1 million tuples per second. So if I plugin the rule engine in one of the bolt, it will sure degrade the STORM performance drastically I guess.

I want to embed drool rule engine in storm so that rule engine becomes horizontally scalable as bolt is.

Please let me know your suggestions on this.

Thank you

Comment: I think your question is too vague. What do you mean by "fast enough"? Basically, you won't use storm's strength for computations (using drools instead) but will rely on its architecture for scalability. Doing multiple things concurrently on different machines can be considered "fast" but of course the bolt with drools will surely be "slow". It all depends on what you expect... Also do you use a DB behind Drools too (which can slows down the whole thing again)?

Comment: Thank you for reply zenbeni. Yes there is an access to DB as well behind rules.